# How to dynamically set drawable resource to ImageView?

Tags: android, mobile-development

I use function `drawCircle(int diameter)` to return `ShapeDrawable` object, which is an OvalShape. Then I use `ImageView.setImageDrawable()` to set the OvalShape. But the `ImageViews` are still empty. How to do it correctly?

Function `drawCircle()`:

```
public ShapeDrawable drawCircle (int diameter) {
        OvalShape ovalShape = new OvalShape();
        ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(ovalShape);
        drawable.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorHint));
        drawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        drawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth((float)2);
        drawable.setBounds(0 ,0, diameter, diameter);

        return drawable;
    }
```

Set `ImageView`:

```
one_img.setImageDrawable(drawCircle(selector_one_diameter));
two_img.setImageDrawable(drawCircle(selector_two_diameter));
```

Above all, I tried using `.xml` file to describe oval shapes. But since values in `dimens.xml` cannot be re-written in Java code, I can't dynamically change the size of oval shapes. It couldn't be better if you can suggest another way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to you have not set widht, height to your drawable. You can set a default size using below code.

```
drawable.setIntrinsicWidth(); 
drawable.setIntrinsicHeight();
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. By the way, how to set stroke color? I can only find method setStrokeWidth()

Comment: you are using setColor(), try changing color using it. you can mark answer as accepted if it worked for you.